# Dudamobile working process

Tags: jquery, html, css

Dudamobile is basically a conversion website which converts existing desktop website to mobile website in seconds.

```
  http://www.dudamobile.com/
```

But I'm unable to get it's working procedure, like what's going on in the background process to achieve this, via code?
While conversion it displays processing as:
1) Building CSS and HTML
2) Analyzing navigation, color and content
3) Testing mobile website

But how exactly does that work, if I want my own such website.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From what I read on their website, seems that they don't really make your current website into a responsive one, but rather just extract content from your website and create a new mobile site on some kind of template.

Quoting:

> - We collect content from your desktop site, Facebook and other social
>     media pages to create an outstanding mobile website
> - Your new mobile
>     site updates automatically whenever changes are made to its desktop
>     counterpart
> - This is all done without ever affecting your current
>     desktop site

So it's more like a templating engine than a tool that converts static desktop website to a mobile one.

Comment: Yes, but the converted mobile website is responsive.

Comment: @Pratiti - it is - but it does not convert the code of your website - it just extracts the content into a new responsive template.

Comment: True. But how does it manage with the layouts compression and setup into a mobile website in such a short span of time?

Comment: @Pratiti - Suspect they are using some kind of crawler that indexes page links, images, social media links, and other relevant stuff and than just outputs it into a new template. It's the same as price aggregate sites do.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, it takes your data and extract some content like logo, colors scheme and references to the content (like a DOM structure).

The problem with this approach is that you have a lot of content to remove and it's not very well adapted and optimized to your web users so in some times you need to make again from scratch.

I recommend more creating your mobile website from the beginning, mainly because User Experience is important if you want a good conversion in your site. You need to focus in your users. That is the reason because very well known frameworks like Bootstrap or Foundation are chaning to Mobile First.

If you want other similar tool to create mobile sites, you can try [Mobsyte](http://www.mobsyte.com)